# Help about sed command

Tags: command-line, sed

A Linux textbook covering sed command gives me an example as follow:

```
sed -e 's/\(<[^ ]*>\)\([ ]*\)\(<[^ ]*>\)/\3\2\1/g'
GNU Linux is cool
Linux GNU cool is
```

but while I typing exactly the same command as the about one, it shows me:

```
sed -e 's/\(<[^ ]*>\)\([ ]*\)\(<[^ ]*>\)/\3\2\1/g'
GNU Linux is cool
GNU Linux is cool
```

Anyone can help me solve this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Many thanks.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the input source for sed.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Just `echo "GNU Linux is cool" | sed ...` - They're doing it interactivly above but echo/pipe is quicker for testing.

Comment: If an answer solves your issue please take a minute and check the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may just be a problem with the forum formatting, but the `<` and `>` are presumably intended to be *word anchors* and as such need backslash escapes `\<` and `\>`

```
sed -e 's/\(\<[^ ]*\>\)\([ ]*\)\(\<[^ ]*\>\)/\3\2\1/g'
```

i.e.

```
echo 'GNU Linux is cool'| sed -e 's/\(\<[^ ]*\>\)\([ ]*\)\(\<[^ ]*\>\)/\3\2\1/g'
Linux GNU cool is
```

However like the previous posters I'd also suggest using the GNU `-r` extended form to cut down the number of escapes

```
sed -re 's/(\<[^ ]*\>)([ ]*)(\<[^ ]*\>)/\3\2\1/g'
```

The word anchors would not seem to be necessary at all if you change the `*` (zero or more) to `+` (one or more)

```
echo 'GNU Linux is cool'| sed -re 's/([^ ]+)([ ]+)([^ ]+)/\3\2\1/g'
Linux GNU cool is
```

Comment: thanks steeldriver, it solves my problem. BTW, any other case I should use backslash escapes?

Comment: @terdon sorry, i forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know. There were a few problems here:

- You need extended mode on for these matches (`-r`)
- You don't need script mode on (`-e`) but that wasn't an error
- There was a lot of bracket escaping which was syntatically incorrect ( you needed those to match)
- I couldn't work out what the angle brackets were for at all. So I nuked them.
- `/g` global mode breaks it because it swaps the last three words and breaks the space. Try it if you like.

And here it is working:

```
$ echo "GNU Linux is cool" | sed -r "s/([^ ]*)([ ]*)([^ ]*)/\3\2\1/"
Linux GNU is cool
```

A better/shorter/easier-to-read way to do this would be to nuke the second group and just use a literal space. Like so:

```
$ echo "GNU Linux is cool" | sed -r "s/([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)/\2 \1/"
Linux GNU is cool
```